# Magento 2 problems with Vagrant and Mac Os

Tags: magento2, vagrant

I'm new on Magento2 and I've seen that the best practice to develop with Magento2 is to use Vagrant.

I have followed several tutorials about setting up Vagrant for Magento on Mac OS El Capitan/Sierra but I've found several issues.

From the command line I always have permission issues even if files have correct permissions.

I read that it could be a NFS problem and also that there is a bug in El Capitan/Sierra with NFS.

I didn't have any problems with Ubuntu instead

Is there someone that uses Vagrant with Mac OS that could help me to figure out with the configuration?

Comment: As an alternative, try using https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers which is specifically designed for Magento 2 developers. And works great on El Capitan with NFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use puphpet.com to generate a new vagrant.
Choose NFS as shared folder type.
Set everything else as you please.

After you `vagrant up` the machine go into the machine with `vagrant ssh`.
Then `sudo su www-data`.
From there do anything you need to.

For me everything works except deletion of files. For this, I have to manually delete them via finder. Like pub/static, view/preprocessed...
It seems to work from Magento itself.
But be aware of side-effects like this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10972
Other than that it works as expected.

In the GitHub issue, one user proposed to use https://github.com/weprovide/valet-plus
If you don't need to replicate server setup that might be another thing to try too.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, the link you provided about Valet could be a good solution.